# Как программно сделать запрет на удаление строк в листе?

Tags: excel, vba

Каким образом программно можно организовать запрет на удаление строк в листе? Можно ли обработать какое событие или пункт "Удалить" сделать недоступным?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Sheet.Protect AllowDeletingRows:=False`

Comment: Какой смысл запрещать удаление строк через меню, если остаются другие варианты: макросом, через закладку *Главная-Удалить*. Уточните задачу.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Да, необходимо запретить удаление не только в контекстном меню.

Comment: На удаление макросом можно закрыть глаза.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - **защита листа**: на ленте закладка *Рецензирование - Защитить_лист*. Проследить, чтобы галка *Разрешить_удаление_строк* была снята.

То же, но с помощью *VBA*, показал *Akina*

**Вариант без применения VBA и без защиты листа** (или с защитой при разрешении удаления строк в других диапазонах). Не даст удалять строки ни вручную, ни макросом (естественно, если в коде не пописан обход такой защиты).

Выделить диапазон ячеек в свободном столбце. В строку формул вписать любую простую формулу:

```
=A1
```

Не выходя со строки формул, ввести формулу массива - нажать одновременно *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* (формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками). Столбец можно скрыть от посторонних глаз.

Хитрость в том, что формула массива, введенная в диапазон, не даст удалять строки в этом диапазоне.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант как скрыть в контекстном меню пункт "Удалить".

```
Sub УдалитьПунктМеню(flag)
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim УдаляемыйПункт As CommandBarControl
  Dim КонтекстноеМеню As CommandBar

  For Each КонтекстноеМеню In Application.CommandBars //каждое меню
    For Each УдаляемыйПункт In КонтекстноеМеню .Controls // каждый пункт
       If InStr(1, УдаляемыйПункт .TooltipText, "Удалить") Then УдаляемыйПункт .Enabled = flag
    Next УдаляемыйПункт 
 Next КонтекстноеМеню 
End Sub
```

Comment: Я очень-очень слабо разбираюсь в макросах. Скопировала предложенный выше макрос (Sub УдалитьПунктМеню(flag)...) в свой файл, но у меня стал неактивным пункт "Удалить" в контекстном меню во всех книгах excel. Как мне сделать этот пункт опять активным, подскажите, пожалуйста? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить значение flag

Comment: Александр,
Спасибо за отзыв. Я не программист. В макросе два раза встречается слово "flag" (в начале "Sub УдалитьПунктМеню(flag)" и ближе к концу "...Then УдаляемыйПункт .Enabled = flag".
Поясните, пожалуйста, два раза заменить на одинаковое значение? На какое именно значение?

Comment: Вообще, это процедура, которой передается параметр flag. Значение или true или false. Вы можете вызвать эту процедуру по событию или из другой процедуры УдалитьПунктМеню(true). В самом коде ничего корректировать не нужно

Comment: Если пункт меню стал недоступным, то как-то вы вызвали эту процедуру. По умолчанию значение false. Я уже и не помню как там в VBA, поэтому могу ошибаться